# PyMongo: How To Search Long value by int value

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm new in both MongoDB and python, and just trying to play with them.

In my one of the first experiments I've faced with some weird thing.

I have an upsert call like this:

```
def update_value(big_int_value: int, bool_value: bool):
    db["my_db"].update_one({"level_1": {"field_1": big_int_value}},
                        {"$set": {"level_1.field_2": bool_value}}, 
                        upsert=True)
```

It successfully inserts the document the first time.
But I have really big int values, so they are saved as `Long('big_int_value')` in mongo:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("6515e4196b6f0a16194b0f58"),
    level_1: { field_1: Long("1144745341514698845"), field_2: true }
  }
```

So when next time I call this `update_one` code again with the same big_int_value, it can't find the already existing document and creates a new one.

I had tried to find the existing records in mongosh and was able to find them only with the following query:

```
db.my_col.find({"level_1.field_1": Long("1144745341514698845")})
```

Without explicit `Long()`, no results found.

I've tried to find the analogue of some casting or wrapping of int to the Mongo-friendly long value in pymongo, but haven't found.

Of course, I have an alternative to store the value not as number, but as string. But I'm curios to see whether there is a native and elegant way to search for mongo's "Long()" values using python's int.

Any info is highly appreciated!

Comment: did you try `bson.int64.Int64` ?

Comment: Nope - unfortunately, I still new records instead of the existing one updated

Comment: Actually, I've found the reason, it was no because of Long type... See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason of the behavior I see in my example.

The problem is in the filter query:

```
db["my_db"].update_one({"level_1": {"field_1": big_int_value}},
                    {"$set": {"level_1.field_2": bool_value}}, 
                    upsert=True)
```

This part is wrong:

```
{"level_1": {"field_1": big_int_value}}
```

In the documentation [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#match-an-embedded-nested-document) it is said:

> To specify an equality condition on a field that is an embedded/nested
> document, use the query filter document { field: value } where
> **value** is the document to match.

So the filter form that used tried to find any results there "level_1" field has a nested document as a value with just one field. But in my structure the nested docs have tro fields.

Changed the query with the right filter form and everything started to work well even without any data convertions:

```
db["my_db"].update_one({"level_1.field_1": big_int_value},
                        {"$set": {"level_1.field_2": bool_value}}, 
                        upsert=True)
```